# How to add an hour to the timestamp in XSLT?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am beginner with XSLT. Would need to add an hour to the timestamp (XSLT 2.0).

<Date1 DateStart="{format-dateTime($completed, '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:00:00Z')}"

<Date2 DateStart="{format-dateTime($completed, '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:00:00Z')}" + 1 hour...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a duration e.g. `current-dateTime() + xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1H')` adds one hour to the `xs:dateTime` returned by `current-dateTime()`. Make sure you do arithmetic operations first one dates/dateTimes and durations and only format the final result.